# Center EditText at the midpoint of a line

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently working on an Android floorplan app. Until now it is possible to draw straight, connected lines on a canvas, where the endpoint is the startpoint of the next line. All lines are stored in an ArrayList with xstart, ystart, xend and yend variables. In my next step I want to place EditText-fields on the midpoint of each line. Unfortunately my code does not work. This is how I tried it:

```
    for (int i=0; i<wallList.size(); i++) {
         double xs=wallList.get(i).getXstart();
         double ys=wallList.get(i).getYstart();
         double xe=wallList.get(i).getXend();
         double ye=wallList.get(i).getYend();
         length= sqrt(Math.pow((xs-xe),2)+Math.pow((ys-ye),2));
         Log.e(TAG, "length: " + String.valueOf(length));
         x_midpoint=(xs+xe)/2;
         y_midpoint=(ys+ye)/2;
         createTextView(length, x_midpoint, y_midpoint);
                    }    

    private void createTextView(double number, double x_midpoint, double y_midpoint){
        EditText text = new EditText(this);
        text.setPadding ((int)y_midpoint, (int)x_midpoint, 0, 0);
        text.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        text.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(number)), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        rl.addView(text);
    }
```

[image: How it is shown]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you see if anything. Have you confirmed that the values in `wallList` are what you expect? If you are targeting >= Honeycomb then you can use `setX` and `setY`. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX(float)).

Comment: I added a picture. setX and setY worked